# Find the index of element in an array against another array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say I have two arrays of objects

```
arrayOne = [{revision: { id: 1 }}, {revision: { id: 2 }}, {revision: { id: 3 }}, {revision: { id: 4 }}]

arrayTwo = [{someOtherProp: { id: 2 }}, {someOtherProp: { id: 4 }}]
```

How do I check the ids in `arrayTwo` against ids in `arrayOne` and returns the result index of the similar id occurrences like so `[1, 3]` (based on `arrayOne` we can see on index 1 and index 3 have ids that occur in `arrayTwo`)

Comment: The question is a little ambiguous. Please add more details

Comment: hmm what other details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```js
arrayOne = [{revision: { id: 1 }}, {revision: { id: 2 }}, {revision: { id: 3 }}, {revision: { id: 4 }},{revision: { id: 5 }}];

arrayTwo = [{someOtherProp: { id: 2 }}, {someOtherProp: { id: 4 }}];

console.log(arrayOne.filter(o1 => arrayTwo.some(o2 => o1.revision.id === o2.someOtherProp.id)).map(x => arrayOne.findIndex(y => y.revision.id === x.revision.id))); // [1, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for your case:

```
one = [{revision: { id: 1 }}, {revision: { id: 2 }}, {revision: { id: 3 }}, {revision: { id: 4 }}]

two = [{someOtherProp: { id: 2 }}, {someOtherProp: { id: 4 }}]

for(let i in two) {
  for(let j in one) {
    if(two[i]['someOtherProp']['id']==one[j]['revision']['id']){
      console.log(i,j)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this implement:

```
arrayOne = [{revision: { id: 1 }}, {revision: { id: 2 }}, {revision: { id: 3 }}, {revision: { id: 4 }},{revision: { id: 5 }}];
arrayTwo = [{someOtherProp: { id: 2 }}, {someOtherProp: { id: 4 }}];

arrayTwo.map(v=>{return v['someOtherProp']['id']}).map(v=>{
    return arrayOne.map(v=>{return v['revision']['id']}).indexOf(v)
})
```